# Adding capability to convert html into a msword document

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache-poi

I am adding capability in my application to convert html into a msword document.

I am trying to use Apache POI to integrate in my application but I didn't find anything related that help me to integrate the Apache-POI with Ruby ( Ruby-On-Rails application).

If you have any idea or source, then please let me know .

Any help will be really appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on the url : http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Need-help-to-create-MS-Word-Doc-using-POI-HWPF-td2303656.html

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, there are 3 ways to get HTML into Word:

The first is to feed Word an HTML document.

The second is to create a docx containing an altChunk/alternative format input part containing the HTML, which Word can process when the docx is first opened.

The third is to convert the HTML yourself. As from 2.8.0, docx4j (to which I'm a committer) can convert XHTML to docx content for you.  It converts CSS styles to Word formatting.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in details . Is docx4j is better then ApachePOI HWPFDocument?

Comment: Its not a question of better (note, docx4j is 'my' project), but different.  The point here is that it can convert HTML to docx for you (provided you tidy it to be well formed XML first).  See http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-2-8-0-released/